# JOINing three tables, query not working as expected in SQLite

Tags: android, sqlite

I'm building an app that searches for recipes by ingredients. I have 5 tables:

**Recipe**

```
RecipeId | RecipeTitle | Directions | PrepTime | CookTime
```

**Ingredient**

```
IngredientId | IngredientName
```

**Category**

```
CategoryId | CategoryName
```

**RecipeIngredient** junction table (many-to-many)

```
RecipeId | IngredientId | Quantity | UOM | Comments
```

**RecipeCategory** junction table (many-to-many)

```
RecipeId | CategoryId
```

What I want to do is let the user choose the ingredients, categories, and time and the app will search for recipes fitting the user's input. I'm testing how this would work using DB Browser for SQLite before implementing it in my app, but it isn't working as expected.

Here's the latest query I've tried (of course I'm assuming user input here, and they aren't limited by the number of ingredients and categories they can choose):

```
SELECT RecipeTitle, COUNT(RecipeTitle) AS Ing FROM Recipe

JOIN RecipeIngredient ON Recipe.RecipeId = RecipeIngredient.RecipeId
JOIN RecipeCategory ON Recipe.RecipeId = RecipeCategory.RecipeId

WHERE
    RecipeIngredient.IngredientId = 
    (SELECT Ingredient.IngredientId FROM Ingredient
    WHERE Ingredient.IngredientName = "olive oil")
OR
    RecipeIngredient.IngredientId = 
    (SELECT Ingredient.IngredientId FROM Ingredient
    WHERE Ingredient.IngredientName = "beef")
OR
    RecipeIngredient.IngredientId = 
    (SELECT Ingredient.IngredientId FROM Ingredient
    WHERE Ingredient.IngredientName = "parsley")
AND
    RecipeCategory.CategoryId = 
    (SELECT Category.CategoryId FROM Category
    WHERE Category.CategoryName = "Dinner")
AND
    Recipe.PrepTime + Recipe.CookTime < 35 -- In minutes

GROUP BY RecipeTitle
ORDER BY Ing DESC -- Orders results by recipes that have the most out of the ingredients the user chose, with less relevant recipes at the bottom
```

Here are the problems I'm having:

- I want `COUNT(RecipeTitle)` to count how many of the ingredients chosen are in every recipe in the results, but instead it's also counting the category as well.
- Category and time search aren't working. It's indeed displaying recipes that contain the chosen ingredients, but also displaying ones that aren't `Dinner` and that require a total time of 35 minutes or over.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
SELECT RecipeTitle, COUNT(Ingredient.IngredientId) AS Ing 
FROM Recipe
JOIN RecipeIngredient ON Recipe.RecipeId = RecipeIngredient.RecipeId
JOIN RecipeCategory ON Recipe.RecipeId = RecipeCategory.RecipeId
JOIN Ingredient ON RecipeIngredient.IngredientId = Ingredient.IngredientId 
JOIN Category ON CategoryCategoryId = RecipeCategory.CategoryId
WHERE Ingredient.IngredientName IN ('olive oil', 'beef', 'parsley')
AND Category.CategoryName = 'Dinner'
AND (Recipe.PrepTime + Recipe.CookTime) < 35
GROUP BY RecipeTitle
ORDER BY Ing DESC
```

Comment: It was telling me there's no such column as `Category.CategoryName`, but then I joined the `Category` table, and it's working now! Thank you. I have a question though. Is it okay to join 4 tables? Is it good practice?

Comment: Ok, thank you for the help. I should join the Category table as well then, like I did, right?

Comment: Yes, I just forgot to add it. Updated it now.